# Persistent segmentation fault in student grading array program

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop

Creating a program that first takes in maximum amount of points for four assignments. Then it must take in seven students' scores for those four assignments. The program must then output each of the seven students score over the total available points. I can't figure out this pesky segmentation error. Program compiles and input of the maximum points available for the four assignments works just fine, the segmentation comes when I try to enter the students scores. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int array[4][8];
    int max, rows, cols, count;

    printf("Please enter the maximum points available for the four assignment");
    printf(" (add a space behind each and return when finished): \n");
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &array[0][0], &array[1][0], &array[2][0], &array[3][0]);

    max=array[0][0]+array[1][0]+array[2][0]+array[3][0];

    printf("Please enter each students set of scores"); 
    printf(" (return after each individual score): \n");

    for(cols=1; cols<8; cols++)
    {
            for(rows=0; rows<4; rows++)
            {
                    scanf("%d", array[rows][cols]);
            }
    }

    for(count=1; count<8; count++)
    {
            for(cols=1; cols<8; cols++)
            {
            printf("The points for student #%d, count");
            printf(" (%d / %d)",array[0][cols]+array[1][cols]+array[2][cols]+array[3][cols], max);
            printf("\n");
            }
    }


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: any reason your cols start at `1` in the for() loops, but you're storing into/accessing the `0` column in your scanf and max lines?

Comment: `scanf("%d", array[rows][cols]);` --> `scanf("%d", &array[rows][cols]);`

Comment: @MarcB `cols:0` Used.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you all. Had to change my second set of for loops because the program would output all 7 sets of scores for each student number, which in total put out 49 lines instead of 7. Now it works perfectly, thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your quotes is misplaced. Change

```
printf("The points for student #%d, count");
```

to

```
printf("The points for student #%d", count);
```